# HTML5 Without Https

Tags: html, http, https

I would like to have a file (ex. index.html)  where i can use html5 for video.
I would like to access this file from my webbrowser locally. Without the need of a website.

I have tried using this on my pc locally, but it would not execute the html5.
I then have pushed it to my website which does have https:// and the videoplayer worked the way it was supposed to.

```
<video id="videoPlayer" src="a.mp3" autoplay autobuffer controls />

<script type="text/javascript">
var nextVideo = "b.mp3";
var videoPlayer = document.getElementById('videoPlayer');
videoPlayer.onended = function(){
videoPlayer.src = nextVideo;
}
</script>
```

This code will not have the html5 functions available. 
I tried using this code with the chrome plugin pitch shifter without succes (local) while on my server it would work perfectly

Answer (score 0):

I'd comment instead of answering but i am not allowed to.
The problem you encounter is not reproduceable in Chrome Version 61.0.3163.100 on Windows 10 - 64 bit. IE, edge, FF and chrome work with your code (but 2 mp4 files instead of your mp3's) locally for me.

What does the Console output of the F12 debug tools write when you attempt to load it locally?